# android - Making a view "GONE" results in the view below it to be invisible as well

Tags: android, listview, spinner, android-relativelayout, visibility

I'm new to android and I'm working on an app for few weeks.

As the title says, the problem that I have is when I want to programmatically set a `Spinner` to GONE, a `ListView` that is below it in a `RelativeLayout` is also gone.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tableSelector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/insertList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableSelector"
        android:layout_above="@+id/saveButton"
        android:background="#aaffffff"
        android:divider="#11000000"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

    </ListView>

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/button_save"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how I set it programmatically:

```
switch(spinnerFlag)
{
    case SPINNER_HIDDEN: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.GONE); break;
    case SPINNER_VISIBLE: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); break;
    case SPINNER_VISIBLE_DISABLED: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                                      tableSelector.setEnabled(false); 
                                      break;
    default: Log.d("onActivityCreated - InserFragment", "Spinner flag < " + spinnerFlag + " > does not exist. Spinner is now visible enabled.");
}
```

This works fine for case `SPINNER_VISIBLE` and `SPINNER_VISIBLE_DISABLED`, but when setting it to `SPINNER_HIDDEN` the `ListView` also dissapears.

**UPDATED**
 As Psy Duck and Nguyen Doan Tung suggested I added the `layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` attribute to the `ListView`. However i noticed it still didn't work. I set the visibility of `ListView` to `visible` in the xml and it is displayed, but it's empty.
 So it solved the problem that I was having, but I have another problem now with the ListView being empty (I'll mention again that when the `(spinnerFlag == SPINNER_VISIBLE || spinnerFlag == SPINNER_VISIBLE_DISABLED)`, it works just fine)

Here is a larger part of my code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        insertList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.insertList);
        /* Some code */

        tableSelector = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableSelector);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,tables);
        tableSelector.setAdapter(adapter);
        tableSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        /* Some code containing some Log.d() */
        });
        /* Some code */
        Log.d("Insert fragment", "Setting table selected by position in list " + pos + ", " + tName);

        tableSelector.setSelection(pos); // pos is calculated correctly in the code i didn't show

        switch(spinnerFlag)
        {
            case SPINNER_HIDDEN: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.GONE); break;
            case SPINNER_VISIBLE: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); break;
            case SPINNER_VISIBLE_DISABLED: tableSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                                              tableSelector.setEnabled(false); 
                                              break;
            default: Log.d("onActivityCreated - InserFragment", "Spinner flag < " + spinnerFlag + " > does not exist. Spinner is now visible enabled.");
        }
    }
```

The `Log` before the `tableSelector.setSelection(pos)` is shown in the LogCat, but none of the `Logs` from the `tableSelector.onItemSelected();` is displayed, so the setSelection doesn't call it.
Any ideea why this might be? (I was thinking that setting a`View` to GONE might stop it functionality, but I `setSelection()` before setting it to GONE)

Thank you!

**FIXED** 
Instead of:

```
 tableSelector.setVisibility(View.GONE); break;
```

I used the workaround:

```
tableSelector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
tableSelector.setEnabled(false);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) tableSelector.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
tableSelector.setLayoutParams(params);
break;
```

And it now works as I needed it.

Comment: When a view is set to GONE it doesn't take any space in the layout. Your ListView has this attr `android:layout_below="@+id/tableSelector"` which will look for Spinner to set ListView below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line to your listview `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/insertList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableSelector"
    android:layout_above="@+id/saveButton"
    android:background="#aaffffff"
    android:divider="#11000000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:visibility="gone" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: Please take a look on the updated version of my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When a view is set to GONE it doesn't take any space in the layout. Your `ListView` has this attr `android:layout_below="@+id/tableSelector"` which will look for `Spinner` to set `ListView` below it.

To avoid that you could simply add the line `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` to your `ListView`, in that way it will ignore looking for Spinner when it's missing and will cover it's place as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please take a look on the updated version of my question. Thank you!